# how can i send a keyboard event to the app through pressing a button?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

in fact i am building a virtual keyboard
how can i send a keyboard event to the program through pressing a button?
thanks

Answer (score 12):

You could use [Quartz Event Servcices](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html).
They provide `CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent` which allows you to emulate any physical key-press.
The API is modeled after real key events.
So you have to call "Shift" + "Character" to get an upper case letter. You also need to release keys you have pressed.
Apple's documentation [contains sample code](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent).

**Update:**
We are talking about Mac OS X, right?  Please add some tags to your original question.